# Espressif ESP8266 NONOS_SDK - Makefile

Tags: makefile, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I would like to compile my source-code for the ESP8266 (Extensa NONOS_SDK Toolchain is already installed and working).

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I use this Makefile from an example from Espressif: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/blob/master/examples/simple_pair/Makefile

and I also use this `gen_misc.sh`: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/blob/master/examples/simple_pair/gen_misc.sh

I am running Ubuntu 18 as a Linux Subsystem for Windows 10. This is how I called `gen_misc.sh` from cmd:

```
./gen_misc.sh
gen_misc.sh version 20150511

Please follow below steps(1-5) to generate specific bin(s):
STEP 1: choose boot version(0=boot_v1.1, 1=boot_v1.2+, 2=none)
enter(0/1/2, default 2):
0
boot mode: old

STEP 2: choose bin generate(0=eagle.flash.bin+eagle.irom0text.bin, 1=user1.bin, 2=user2.bin)
enter (0/1/2, default 0):
0
ignore boot
generate bin: eagle.flash.bin+eagle.irom0text.bin

STEP 3: choose spi speed(0=20MHz, 1=26.7MHz, 2=40MHz, 3=80MHz)
enter (0/1/2/3, default 2):
2
spi speed: 40 MHz

STEP 4: choose spi mode(0=QIO, 1=QOUT, 2=DIO, 3=DOUT)
enter (0/1/2/3, default 0):
2
spi mode: DIO

STEP 5: choose spi size and map
    0= 512KB( 256KB+ 256KB)
    2=1024KB( 512KB+ 512KB)
    3=2048KB( 512KB+ 512KB)
    4=4096KB( 512KB+ 512KB)
    5=2048KB(1024KB+1024KB)
    6=4096KB(1024KB+1024KB)
    7=4096KB(2048KB+2048KB) not support ,just for compatible with nodeMCU board
    8=8192KB(1024KB+1024KB)
    9=16384KB(1024KB+1024KB)
enter (0/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9, default 0):
4
spi size: 4096KB
spi ota map:  512KB + 512KB
```

This is what I get as output:

```
start...

make: Nothing to be done for 'FORCE'.
```

Any ideas or help what I am doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

Please don't hesitate do ask if I didn't include any information you might need to answer this question.

Comment: Looking at the Makefile, I can't tell what's supposed to happen here. The last line of `gen_misc.sh` calls make with no target. Therefore, the Makefile uses the default target, which is FORCE. The FORCE target is empty. Therefore, it does nothing. Does the documentation tell you to modify these files and put your own targets in?

Comment: https://github.com/hannes-angst/esp-led-strip/blob/master/Makefile

Answer (score 0):

the solution as suggested [here](http://iot-bits.com/articles/building-examples-in-esp8266-non-os-sdk-v-2-0-0/) is to copy the folder where you are running the script to the root of the sdk folder  and run the script.